# Symfony Translation: Correct usage of default %count% in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

By looking in a [Testcase](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Tests/Extension/TranslationExtensionTest.php#L99) I found out, that it should be possible to get the value passed to `transchoice` via the `%count%` variable. I got an array and tried to use this with the item count of this array:

> {% transchoice array|length %}array.elements{% endtranschoice %}

My translation file is `messages.en.yml` and contains this entry:

> array.elements: "{0} No entries | {1} One entry | ]1,Inf[ %count% entries"

Now I got following result:

> %count% entries

So I tried the other possibilities:

> {% set count=array|length %}
>   {% transchoice count %}array.elements{% endtranschoice %}
>   {% transchoice array|length %}{0} No entries | {1} One entry | ]1,Inf[ %count% entries{% endtranschoice %}
>   {% transchoice count %}{0} No entries | {1} One entry | ]1,Inf[ %count% entries{% endtranschoice %}

With this result:

> %count% entries
>   3 entries
>   3 entries

I know I could just add `with {"%count%": count}` and the first two examples would work.

**So my question is**: Is this a bug, a missing improvement or did I do something wrong? If so, how should I do it?
I found bug [#8404](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8408) that could be related to this.

Additional information:
Symfony 3.1, PHP 7.0, Twig 1.26

Comment: Does it work when you use `{{ "array.elements"|transchoice(count) }}`?

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Both `{{ "array.elements"|transchoice(array|length) }}` and `{{ "array.elements"|transchoice(count) }}` work. This is a good alternative at the moment.